# exp(log + log) for positive semidefinite matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, logarithms, terminology, matrix-equations

Let $A$ and $B$ be positive definite matrices.  What is known about $f(A,B)=\exp(\log A + \log B)$?  Does this function have a name?  This is interesting because $f(A,B) = AB$ for commuting matrices and $f(A,B)=f(B,A)$ even for non-commuting matrices.

Comment: You might be interested in this [more general question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1785761/is-there-a-name-for-the-operation-f-1fx-oplus-fy)?

Comment: Does this distribute over $+$?

Comment: No, $f(a+b, c) \ne f(a,c) + f(b,c)$ (checked numerically).

Comment: The title says positive semidefinite, but the question text says positive definite. Can $f$ be defined also for positive *semi*definite matrices (this is a question I just asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4535569/interpreting-exp-frac12-logp-frac12-logq-for-singular-symm))?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $\log(A)$ and $\log(B)$ are symmetric matrices, by the [Golden-Thompson theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden%E2%80%93Thompson_inequality#Statement) we have
$$
\text{tr}\big(f(A,B)\big)
\le \text{tr}\big(\exp\big(\log(A)\big)\exp\big(\log(B)\big)\big)
=\text{tr}(AB).
$$

Comment: Thanks.  And equality iff $A$ and $B$ commute: Petz (1994) A survey of certain trace inequalities.  That paper has some other interesting stuff.  I'll leave the question open for a bit to see if there are other answers.

Answer (score 1):

Petz (1994) *A survey of certain trace inequalities*, Lemma 4 leads to

$f(A, B) = \lim_{s \to \infty} (A^{1/s} B^{1/s})^s$

This gives a nice Lie algebra geometric interpretation: suppose Alice is trying to rotate in the $\log A$ direction and Bob is trying to rotate in the $\log B$ direction.  They compromise and rotate in the $\log A + \log B$ direction, or take turns rotating an infinitesimal amount.