# Identity element of a group, help

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

[image]

So far I have done the RHS to $(x-3)(y-3)+12$ and I have done this to find the identity element, $(e-3)(x-3)+12=x$, then re-arranged to $(e-3)=(x-12)/(x-3)$, now I am stuck.

Comment: Apply definition of identity element. Put $y=0$ in $x*y=y$.

Comment: Again one of the various variations of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2184693/prove-that-a-b-a-b-ab-defines-a-group-operation-on-bbb-r-setminus).

Comment: $e=4$ will do the job for the identity.

Comment: You factored wrong. It factors as $(x-3)(y-3)+3$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $e$ denote the identity element. Then: $0=0*e=-3e+12$. This gives $e=4.$

Answer (score 1):

The identity element (if it exists) is a value $e$ such that

$x*e = x \space \forall x$

Note that the symmetry of the definition of $x*y$ tells us that

$x*e = x \space \forall x \Rightarrow e*y = y \space \forall y$

so if we can find $e$ then it will be a two-sided identity.

$x*e = x \space \forall x \\
\Rightarrow xe -3x - 3e + 12 = x \space \forall x \\
\Rightarrow x(e-4) -3e +12 = 0 \space \forall x \\
\Rightarrow (x-3)(e-4)= 0 \space \forall x$

From this can you see a value for $e$ which will act as an identity ?

Answer (score 0):

Note that in any group $G$, the identity is the unique solution to the equation $g^2=g$.

Hence, the identity in your group is the unique solution to the equation $x^2-6x+12=x$ in ${\mathbf R}\setminus \{3\}$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: Show that the function $f(x)=x-3$ defines an isomorphism between your group and the group of nonzero real numbers with multiplication. Note that this way, you can simultaneously check that this formula really defines a group operation.